# Browser cannot find function, possibly an error with internally calling from an external file?

Tags: jquery, function, autocomplete

I keep receiving an "Uncaught TypeError: "x" is not a function" error. I believe it may have to do with how I'm calling the function internally within the HTML, but storing the function from an external file, but all of my researching shows that this shouldn't be an issue at all.

I've even placed the script link to the external higher in the html file in case cascading loading is causing the function to be called before it's found where it's defined, but I believe that javascript doesn't really ... do that?

I've done a lot of troubleshooting on this, and every validator I've tried is saying my JS is clean, and I changed the function name from "autocomplete" to "searchBar" hoping it was just that autocomplete is a reserved word or something, but no dice.

I also got the same error with the stackoverflow code snippet, even though I'm calling the function in the same document *after* it's been defined, so now I'm not sure what the issue could be?

```js
function searchBar(arr) {

  var currentFocus,
      inp = $(this),
      wrapper = $('.autocomplete-wrapper');

  // when triggering input is changed, run function
  $(this).change(function() {
    var a = $(this).sibling().find('.autocomplete-item-wrapper'),
        b,
        i,
        val = $(this).value;

    closeAllLists();

    if (!val) return false;

    currentFocus = -1;

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].substring(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
        // creates a div element for each matching element
        b = document.createElement('div');

        // makes the matching letters bold
        b.html("<strong>" + arr[i].substring(0, val.length) + "</strong");
        b.innerHTML += arr[i].substring(val.length);

        // inserts a input field that will hold the current array item's value
        b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";

        // inserts the item into the input when clicked
        b.click(function(e) {
            inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
            closeAllLists();
        });
        a.append(b);
      };
    };
  });

  inp.keydown(function(e) {
    var x = a;
    if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { // arrow down
      currentFocus++;
      /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
      addActive(x);
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
      /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
      decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
      currentFocus--;
      /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
      addActive(x);
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
      e.preventDefault();
      // if (currentFocus > -1) {
      //   /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
      //   if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
      // }
    }
  });

  function addActive(x) {
    // a function to classify an item as "active"
    if (!x) return false;

    // start by removing the "active" class on all items
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  };

  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  };

  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  };
};


var options = ["acorn squash","alfredo sauce","alligator","almond extract","almonds","anchovy","anchovy paste","angelica","apple butter","applesauce","apricots","artichokes","baking soda","barbecue sauce"];

$("#searchbar").searchBar('options');
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

.search::after {
  content: '';
  display:table;
  clear: both;
}

.search {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 5rem auto;
}

input {
  height: 3rem;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

input[type="search"] {
  width: calc(100% - 4rem);
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  width: 4rem;
  background: DodgerBlue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="search">
  <input id="searchbar" type="search">
  <input type="submit">
  <div class="autocomplete-wrapper">
    <div class="autocomplete-item-wrapper">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- For the sake of showing how I'm linking files and calling the function.
<!-- jQuery - - >
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Autocomplete - - >
<script src="js/search-autocomplete.js"></script>


<script>
  var options = {
     url: "js/searchterms.js"
  };

  $("#searchbar").searchBar('options');
</script> -->
</body>
```

This code is heavily following [W3School's tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete) on creating an autocomplete.

Comment: You have defined `searchBar` as a function, not as a jQuery plugin, hence `$.searchBar()` does not exist. If you want to create a plugin [this tutorial](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/). Also note that W3Schools is notoriously inaccurate. I wouldn't recommend anyone use them at all. There are far better sources, such as Codecademy

Comment: Cool, I can't upvote comments, but thanks. That's ... frustrating since it says function. But good to know!